# parsing text with Parse::RecDescent

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse some text with Parse::RecDescent

```
from :

x=2 and y=2 and f=3 and (x has 3,4 or r=5 or r=6 ) and z=2

to something like :



x equal 2 and y equal 2 and f equal 3 and (( x contains 3 or x contains 4 or r equal 5 or requal 6 )) and z equal 2
```

other example :

```
input :

x= 3 and y has 5 and (z has 6 or z=3 ) and f=2



output :


x equals 3 and (( y contains 5)) and ((z has 6 or z equals 3)) and f equals 2
```

my question if i find a list of those operators :

has ,or

i should put "((" before the code and "))" after the code as mentioned on the example aboves

is it possible to do something like this with Parse::RecDescent ?

Comment: Yes, one can build a parser using P::RD that parses expressions like the one you posted. There's nothing special about it.

Comment: Thanks ikegami , can you show how i parse the logic of adding '(' and trailing ')' when there are multiple OR operators ?

Comment: Parsing means giving meaning to the tokens of a string, i.e. identifying the different operators, terms and whatnot with the help of a grammar. It's the first thing you need to do, before you even think of output. Are you asking help determining the grammar? If so, where's your attempt? Even if you ignore the code parts for now, it would be something

Comment: Parens are usually done like this: `term: ident | '(' expr ')'`. You should look at other grammars for guidance. Parsing expressions has been done before

Answer (score 1):

The grammar would look something like the following:

```
parse       : expr EOF

expr        : logic_or

# vvv Lowest precedence vvv

logic_or    : <leftop: logic_and LOGIC_OR logic_and>

logic_and   : <leftop: comparison LOGIC_AND comparison>

comparison  : term comparison_[ $item[1] ]
comparison_ : '=' term
            | HAS ident_list
            |

# ^^^ Highest precedence ^^^

ident_list  : <leftop: IDENT ',' IDENT>

term        : '(' expr ')'
            | IDENT


# Tokens

IDENT      : /\w+/

LOGIC_OR   : /or\b/ 
LOGIC_AND  : /and\b/
HAS        : /has\b/

EOF        : /\Z/
```

Now you just need to add the code block to emit the desired output.

In `comparison_`, the LHS term is available as `$arg[0]`.

I had to make some assumptions, so there could be errors.